# Migrate one single project from On-premise TFS to VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

how to migrate a single project alone (where project collection contains 30+ projects) from TFS to VSTS with all history, build-definitions, changesets

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has documentation on this exact scenario which can be found here: [Migrate to Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/?utm_source=ms&utm_medium=guide&utm_campaign=vstsdataimportguide) : Move from Team Foundation Server (TFS) to Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and bring your data along.

**This link also contains the download link for the migration tooling which you will want to use**

> Currently the following versions of TFS are supported for import:
>
> - TFS 2017 Update 3
> - TFS 2018
> - TFS 2018 Update 1

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I have read the Microsoft article but couldn't find any pointer to migrate just one project. They have detailed about migrating TFS project collection to VSTS and we are looking for the migrating just one project out of the whole collection. Can you please help here and suggest which tool/approach we should follow

Comment: Did you take a look at the Migration Options? One of the ways is to manually migrate assets, which may be your best option. They speak about having migrated from TFS and Team Foundation Version Control to VSTS + Git.

Unfortunately in their scenario they intentionally left behind their history and many other important pieces which sound like you want to keep.

[Migration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migrate-to-vsts-from-tfs?view=vsts)

Comment: This is the easiest way. Bring over **everything**, then delete the projects that you don't need.

Comment: Thanks Jesse and Daniel. Yes I guess manually migrating the assets would be the last option. I was actually looking for something which can transfer the history along with other important stuffs. Also the VSTS already have many projects - would it possible to migrate the TFS project to Existing Project collection to VSTS - Please suggest with your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

> As described in [About VSTS and TFS, Scope and scale data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/about-vsts-tfs?view=vsts#scope-scale-data), the
>   long term direction for VSTS is to support grouping of accounts within
>   organizations. This would lead to:
>
> **VSTS accounts that serve as the equivalent of TFS project collections** and VSTS organizations that serve as the equivalent of
>   TFS deployments.
>   **This is why the TFS Database Import Service only supports importing single TFS collections as single VSTS accounts.**
>
> If you need to migrate individual team projects you will need to use
>   one of the other options—manual copy or **public API based
>   migrations.**
>
> *[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migrate-to-vsts-from-tfs?view=vsts#migration-scopes)*

It's very clear why you could not use  TFS Database Import Service  to migrate at team project-level directly.

You can also have a try for [VSTS Sync Migration Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration),it allows you to bulk edit and migrate data between Team Projects on both Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). Note this without history. How to please refer: [TFS 2017 Migration To VSTS with VSTS Sync Migrator](http://mohamedradwan.com/2017/09/15/tfs-2017-migration-to-vsts-with-vsts-sync-migrator/)

If you insist on keeping all history, the only way is using  TFS Database Import Service, you may take the workaround as *Daniel* suggested.

Comment: First link 404s.